# The infinispan cluster node expiration result is inconsistent with the official documentation description

Tags: infinispan

When I tested the expiration method of infinispan cluster node cache, I found that when the node reached the maximum idle time, it would not get "the last time the entry is accessed" from other nodes in the cluster, but directly invalidate the cache entry of the node. For example: I started two nodes A and B, and set the maximum idle time of the cache to 10s. At the beginning of the test, I sent a request to Node A to access the database records and write the database records to the cache. At this time, Node A synchronizes the data cache to Node B. Then at 5s, I accessed the cache entry at Node A, and then at Node B after 10s. I found that the cache entry at Node B was invalid, Node B retrieved the database records from the database, and wrote the cache and synchronized to other nodes, instead of treating the cache as valid.

Why is it different from the description in the document? http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#expiration_details

For the configuration of cluster node cache expiration failure, I configure it as follows:

```java
Configuration C = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .expiration().enableReaper(). wakeUpInterval(50000L).maxIdle(10000l).build();
```

Comment: What is the Infinispan version?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using an older version of Infinispan. Cluster wide max idle expiration wasn't introduced until 9.3 in https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-9003. If this issue still persists with 9.3 or newer, you can log a bug at https://issues.jboss.org/projects/ISPN.